# Connecting Liquibase with SQL Anywhere 17

Tags: liquibase, sqlanywhere, liquibase-pro

I already downloaded liquibase-4.0.0-beta1 and I'm looking to set it up with an existing SQL Anywhere 17 database. I've tried running the following command:

```
liquibase 
--driver=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver 
--classpath=jconn4-4.0.0.jar 
--changeLogFile=testInitialChangelog.sql 
--url="jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=test123456;PreventNotCapable=y" 
--logLevel=debug generateChangeLog
```

The output is:

```
[2020-05-12 12:05:59] INFO [liquibase.integration] No Liquibase Pro license key supplied. Please set liquibaseProLicenseKey on command line or in liquibase.properties to use Liquibase Pro features.
Liquibase Community 4.0.0-beta1 by Datical
Starting Liquibase at 12:05:59 (version 4.0.0-beta1 #6 built at 2020-04-20 18:23+0000)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=test123456;PreventNotCapable=y with driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
[2020-05-12 12:06:00] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=test123456;PreventNotCapable=y with driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=dba;pwd=sql;eng=test123456;PreventNotCapable=y with driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

I have not found information about the connection string (URL) for SQL Anywhere, can anyone help me in what I am doing wrong?

Thanks